# Analyzing previous records to predict expected outcomes

Tags: prediction

I'm one of the directors of a language school. We teach students in different levels (CEFR A1 A2 B1 B2, if you are familiar).

In each level students are evaluated in 10 different exams. At the end of each level, they are either successful and move onto the next level, or unsuccessful and repeat the same level. We have all the data of the past three years, which consists of the data of about 4000 different students.
What I want to learn is, how could we predict the possible future results of our current students based on the previous data? Does it have anything to do with machine learning?

I'm not alien to coding, and if there are similar tutorials, I believe I can do it myself. 
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an interesting problem! For starters you can check the book An Introduction to Statistical Learning (http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/research.html) and learn about classification problems.